# Как обновить таблицу после ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вывел таблицу через PHP, добавил форму редактирования по этой таблице. Написал `ajax` чтобы было без перезагрузки страницы, но загвоздка значения таблицы не обновляются, только после перезагрузки страницы. Что нужно дописать в `ajax`?

```
// Устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
$("#ajax_form").submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
     var form_data = $(this).serialize(); // Собираем все данные из формы
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST", // Метод отправки
         url: "/php/update.php", // Путь до php файла отправителя
         data: form_data,
         success: function () {
             // Код в этом блоке выполняется при успешной отправке сообщения
            
             alert("Изменено!");
        
         }
        
     }); return false;
 });
```

Comment: Вариантов несколько.. Либо отслеживать изменилось значение или нет и менять его "вручную", либо обновлять таблицу через тот же jq load()

Comment: А Вы уверены что serverside DataTable используете?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно дописать в `success` вставку полученного в ответе `POST` значения в `DOM`. То есть у вас должно получиться что-то типа такого, где `data` – это ответ, а `element` – место, куда нужно вставить результат:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='element'></div> // элемент, в который вы вернёте результат
```

**JS:**

```
$("#ajax_form").submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const element = document.getElementById('element') // находите на странице элемент, в который вы хотите вернуть результат
    const form_data = $(this).serialize()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/update.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: data => element.outerHTML = data // вставляете в этот элемент ответ сервера
    }); return false
})
```

И вообще проконсольте ответ вашей функции, чтобы узнать, что она возвращает (и возвращает ли вообще что-то):

`success: data => console.log(data)`

Comment: success: data => document.body.outerHTML = data Сработало. Спасибо

Comment: @savage рад был помочь, обращайтесь.

Comment: Почему то срабатывает только один раз,  и то после ctrl 5. С чем связано не могу понять

Comment: "success: data => document.body.outerHTML = data" в инспекторе заметил, что он создает <head> страницы. я явно делаю что то не то ;D

Comment: @savage document.body.outerHTML надо заменить на элемент, в который вы хотите вставить результат. document.body.outerHTML – это весь документ, временный костыль.

Comment: @savage дописал пример.

Comment: Спасибо все работает. Изначально я пытался вернуть результаты не в пустой контейнер, а в таблицу, и творилась всякая дичь